# Interval of definition of the solutions of $\dot x=e^x\sin x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to prove that the solutions of this ODE

> $\dot x=e^x\sin x$

are defined in $\mathbb R$.

I'm really new on this subject, I'm trying to use the Picard Theorem, but this function is not locally Lipschitz, I need help here.

Comment: Isn't every continuous function locally Lipschitz?

Comment: @JavierBadia No! For example, the cube root at zero

Comment: Isn't every continuously differentiable function locally Lipschitz?

Comment: Anyway, to get your maximal solutions on $\mathbb{R}$, you need Lipschitz in $x$, like with linear ODE's. If it's locally Lipschitz, you only get the existence of maximal solutions (unique for a given initial condition) on some open interval. So you need more than Picard here, since your function is not Lipschitz.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Draw a phase diagram:

- If $x(0)=n\pi$ for some integer $n$, then $x(t)=n\pi$ for every $t\geqslant0$ hence $x$ is defined on $[0,\infty)$.
- If $x(0)=x_0$ with $2n\pi\lt x_0\lt(2n+2)\pi$ for some integer $n$, then $x(t)\to(2n+1)\pi$ when $t\to T$, where $[0,T)$ is the maximal "forward" interval of definition of the function $x$.
  Furthermore,
  $$
  \int_{x_0}^{x(t)}\frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm e^u\sin u}=t,
  $$
  hence the fact that $T=+\infty$ is equivalent to the divergence of the integral
  $$
  \int^{(2n+1)\pi}\frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm e^u\sin u},
  $$
  which is obvious since $\mathrm e^u\to c\ne0$ and $\sin u\sim(2n+1)\pi-u$ when $u\to(2n+1)\pi$.

The same argument used "backwards" shows that $x$ is defined on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I didn't understand why $x(t)=n\pi$ in the first statement. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: In fact, when we derive $x$, we will have the zero function. Is that right?

Comment: If $\dot x=F(x)$ and $F(a)=0$ for some $a$, then $x(0)=a$ implies $x(t)=a$ for every $t$.

Answer (score 2):

**Local existence and uniqueness**

As Erick Wong noted in comments, the function $e^x\sin x$ is continuously differentiable and therefore locally Lipschitz. This ensures the local existence and uniqueness of solutions.

**Stationary solutions**

Some solutions are stationary: $x\equiv \pi n$, $n\in\mathbb Z$. Every non-stationary solution begins with initial value $x(t_0)=x_0$, where $\pi n < x_0<\pi(n+1)$ for some $n\in\mathbb Z$. By uniqueness, solution curves do not cross: therefore, $\pi n < x(t)<\pi(n+1)$ *for all times*.

**Uniformity**

Now that you know that the values of $x$ remain within interval $[\pi n,\pi(n+1)]$, you can give a uniform estimate for $M$ and $L$ in the statement of the [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem). For example, you can take a larger interval $I = [\pi n-1,\pi(n+1)+1]$ (so you have room for $b=1$)*, and then let $M=\sup_I |e^x\sin x|$ and $L=\sup_{I}|(e^x\sin x)'|$. The theorem then gives you $\epsilon>0$ (depending only on $n$) such that the solution of initial value problem $x(t_0)=x_0$ with $\pi n < x_0<\pi(n+1)$ exists in the  interval $(t_0-\epsilon, t_0+\epsilon)$.

**Global existence**

Now that you have a fixed $\epsilon$ independent of $t_0$, you can apply the Picard–Lindelöf theorem repeatedly to get global existence.

**Remark**

To take the suprema over an interval larger than $[\pi n,\pi(n+1)]$  is mathematically unnecessary: the behavior of the right hand side outside of $[\pi n,\pi(n+1)]$ is irrelevant. But it would take some effort to argue this point, while enlarging the interval takes no effort at all.

Comment: why your user name is in grey?

Comment: @user32240 For some reason he left the site

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be having trouble with this. I am switching to an easier problem,
$$ y' = \cos y.   $$
Here the independent variable is $x,$ so you can draw the result in $xy$ graph paper.

Now, there are horizontal lines at $$y = \frac{- \pi}{2}, \; y = \frac{ \pi}{2}, \;y = \frac{3 \pi}{2}, $$ because cosine is zero there and $y$ stays constant.

The thing to expect is that solutions between constant solutions will start near one line and approach the other. And, indeed, for $ \frac{- \pi}{2} < y < \frac{ \pi}{2},$ each solution can be written
$$   y = \arcsin \tanh (x + C),  $$ for some constant $C.$ Such a curve resembles an $\arctan$  curve, and $y$ is exactly zero when $x = -C.$

For $ \frac{ \pi}{2} < y < \frac{3 \pi}{2},$ each solution can be written
$$   y =\pi - \arcsin \tanh (x + C).  $$ Here   $y$ is exactly $\pi$ when $x = -C.$ Also, these resemble an upside down arctan curve.

This pattern continues for $y$ on successive intervals of height $\pi.$

Comment: Thank you, your example is much better to understand what is going on there